# grid view does not show data from database once bind

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, c#-3.0

I have a grid view it has 3 drop down lists and 3 text boxes in template field. On the top of the grid view i have two text boxes( text box 1 and 2) which initilize there values when page is loaded. i also have 3 buttons for add new row , save , search. I want my grid view to show data from database when search button is clicked i.e select * from table where text box 1 and 2 equal to some thing. My HTML looks like.

```
    AutoGenerateColumns="false"        onselectedindexchanged="Gridview1_SelectedIndexChanged" BackColor="White" 
        BorderColor="#336666" BorderStyle="Double" BorderWidth="3px" CellPadding="4" 
        GridLines="Horizontal">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="RowNumber" HeaderText="Row Number" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Item name">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Height="25px" Width="119px" 
          DataTextField = "Item_name" Text='<%# Bind("Item_name") %>'   DataValueField="Item_name" 
                         AppendDataBoundItems="true">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sub item">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" Height="25px" Width="119px" 
               AppendDataBoundItems="true"   
                         DataValueField = "Sub_item" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Sub_item") %>'  DataTextField = "Sub_item"
                           />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Location">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Location") %>' ></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Permit number">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"  Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Permit no") %>' ></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Applied">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" runat="server"

            Height="25px" Width="119px" 
            DataTextField="Text" AppendDataBoundItems="true" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Applied") %>'  DataValueField="Value"  />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Revision">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"  Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Revision") %>' ></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="ButtonSave" runat="server"  Text="Save" OnClick="Save_Click" />
                    <asp:Button ID="ButtonAdd" runat="server"  Text="Add Row" />
                    <asp:Button ID="search" runat="server"  Text="Search"  OnClick="Search_Click"/>

                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
```

on my search button click i have this code

```
     if (TextBox4.Text != null && TextBox5.Text != null)
         {
             string job = TextBox4.Text.ToString();
             string leg = TextBox5.Text.ToString();
             string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
             using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
             using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
             {
                 Response.Write(job);
                 Response.Write(leg);
                 conn.Open();
                 SqlCommand comand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from Billing_heads where job# = '" + job + "' AND leg#='" + leg + "' ", conn);
                // try
                 //{
                     SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(comand);
                     DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                     adp.Fill(ds);
                     //gvPros is the ID of GridView.
                     Gridview1.DataSource = ds;
                     Gridview1.DataBind();
```

Please help me that how can i bind my gridview because in Text='<%# Bind("Item_name") %>'  property it saying the column name it says property with  name "coloumn name " does not exists please help

Comment: Consider using parameters in your SQL query. Is there `Item_name` column in `Billing_heads` table?

Comment: I have changed my query to SELECT Item_name,Sub_item,Location,Permitno,Applied,Revision from Billing_heads where job# = '" + job + "' AND leg#='" + leg + "' still same error @Andrei

Comment: Yes @Andrei Item_name is my column in Billing_heasd